# I want my cube to repeatability move forward for every frame per second in pygame, but I dont know what's wrong?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I think it has something to do with the fact that moving is a event and my function "momentum", is not in there which is how I'm trying to make it move repeatedly. I would like to know what I did wrong and how to think about code [like this] in the future. I just started learning pygame and this is actually my first project using it. I have also been coding for 1 year now (last month marked it) and I really enjoy programming.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
running = True
x = 0
y = 0
momentum = "null"
def draw_rect(x, y, size, size1):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (204, 65, 242), (x, y, size, size1))
def momentum_forward(x, y):
    if momentum == "a":
        x += -25
    if momentum == "d":
        x += 25
    if momentum == "w":
        y += -25
    if momentum == "s":
        y += 25
while running:
    FPS = 8
    fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 480), 0, 32)
    draw_rect(x, y, 25, 25)
    momentum_forward(x, y)
    print(momentum)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x += -25
                momentum = "a"
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x += 25
                momentum = "d"
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                y += -25
                momentum = "w"
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                y += 25
                momentum = "s"
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `x` and `y` to the `momentum_forward` function so updates in the function don't update the global `x` and `y` values.

Try this code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
running = True
x = 0
y = 0
momentum = None  # null in python
def draw_rect(x, y, size, size1):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (204, 65, 242), (x, y, size, size1))
    
def momentum_forward():
    global x,y    # use global variables
    if momentum == "a":
        x += -25
    if momentum == "d":
        x += 25
    if momentum == "w":
        y += -25
    if momentum == "s":
        y += 25
        
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 480), 0, 32)  # only need this once
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    FPS = 8
    momentum_forward()  # don't pass x,y
#    print(momentum)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x += -25
                momentum = "a"
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x += 25
                momentum = "d"
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                y += -25
                momentum = "w"
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                y += 25
                momentum = "s"
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    draw_rect(x, y, 25, 25)
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: I kind of had a suspicion that I needed global variables, but I didn't know that the things in the function were messing it up. Thank you!

Comment: @fredgoodmasn If this answer solved your question, consider marking it as solved.